# How to check User Role and redirect to specific page according to Role when login in Wordpress?

Tags: users, redirect, login

Can anyone tell How to check User Role and redirect to specific page according to Role when login in Wordpress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this redirection with this filter :

```
add_filter("login_redirect", function ($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user) {


    if (    is_a($user, "WP_User")
        &&  user_can($user, "role_to_test")
    ) {

        $redirect_to = home_url("/page_slug/");

    }


    return $redirect_to;

}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check role and redirect to specific page by slug or ID

Check single role.

```
if( current_user_can('editor') ) { 

    $page = get_page_by_title('thank-you');

    wp_redirect(get_permalink($page->ID));

}
```

Check role for multi.

```
if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  

    $page = get_page_by_title('thank-you');

    wp_redirect(get_permalink($page->ID));

}
```